# The distance that CO2 molecules travel in the air before they collide with each other

Tags: kinetic-theory-of-gases

Well the title covers most.
But further at 410 ppm, 1 atm and 23 °C.

I believe they call it the mean free path of CO2-CO2 collisions. So not just the mean free path of CO2 in air colliding with every other molecule substances.

I have zero workexperience with gases so I'm having troubles with this one.
I'm Dutch (sadly) so excuse me in advance if my English isn't correct.

Comment: This is complicated in that the CO2 molecules would collide multiple times with N2 and O2 molecules before colliding with another CO2 molecule. So is this what you really want to calculate?

Comment: I think you should calculate the average interval then assume that about x molecules are CO2 in y total.

Comment: You might be able to approximate with the main free path for any molecule in air and hen adjusting for the concentration of CO2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the probability of one (CO2) molecule being the nearest neighbour of another.

Let $w(r)$ be the probability that the nearest neighbour occurs between distance  $r$ and $r+dr$ (on a spherical surface). This must be the probability than no molecules exist closer to the victim molecule,  which occurs at a distance $r$, and that this molecule exists in the shell $r$ to $r+dr$. Thus,

$$ w(r)=\left(  1-\int_0^r w(r)dr \right)4\pi r^2 n$$

where $n$ is the average number of molecules / unit volume. (1 mol/m<sup>3</sup> $\equiv 10^3N_A/10^{27} = 0.6023 $ molecules / nm$^3$).

Solving this gives

$$ w(r)=4\pi r^2n\exp(-4\pi r^3n/3)$$

This function is zero at zero goes through a maximum and is  small at large. distances, see figure.

If you want a single number then the *average* distance between molecules is

$$\langle r \rangle =\int_0^\infty rw(r)dr =\Gamma (4/3)/(4\pi n/3)^{1/3} =0.55396n^{-1/3}$$

where $n$ is in number of molecules/volume then $n^{-1/3}$ is in units of length.

( $\Gamma(4/3)$ is the gamma function, sort of equivalent to a factorial but for a non-integer number)

The figure below shows $w(r)$ the probability of a near neighbour at distance $r$ for some concentrations.

[image: w(r( vs r]

If what you want is the *total path* taken accounting for all collisions then you would have to start with one the of the $w(r)$ distributions corresponding to your concentration and do a Monte Carlo computer calculation to work out the total path, not easy and v long calculation probably. There will be a statistical mechanics way of calculating this I'm sure but I'm not aware of it at present.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much!! (To bad I don't have software for Monte Carlo simulation). But this was very helpful. Thumbs up.